# How to display all images on my localhost server - localhost / NameOfImage.jpg which actually a folder containing jpg files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, localhost

I want to display all images on my localhost server - `localhost:3500/NameOfImage.jpg` which actually a folder containing JPEG files.

I want to display all the images on `/upload` folder of my server which I have managed to mapp to `localhost:3500` so `localhost:3500/LA.jpg` gives me a single image called "LA"

Basically this folder contains 20 something `.jpg` files which I want to display all of them on my web page - this folder is updated periodically. So after every refresh changes should be visible. I am trying this on my own too.

> @my code is as below 
>   `

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
 <title>Local Server(Folder) Image Display</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div1"><h2>Displaying Uploads</h2></div>
 <button name="button" id="button" type="button">Get Images </button>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
     $("button").click(function(){
  var folder = "localhost:3500/";

  $.ajax({
      url : folder,
      success: function (data) {

              if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|jpg)$/) ) { 
                  $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
               
          });
      }
  });      
 });
});     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble? Please show the code that is giving you a problem.

Comment: @georgeawg - updated the question with my code which is not working out